# Density of distance from orgin in a general disc

Tags: probability, distributions

Consider the disc $|z-c| \leq R.$For the case of a unit disc ,the probability desnity of the distance from origin  of  a randomly and uniformly  chosen point in the disc is given by
\begin{equation}
f(u) = 
\begin{cases}
2u, & \text{if } \quad 0 \leq u \leq 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
However ,it is not  obvious  to me as to how we can find the same in case of the general disc mentioned .

Any help\hints\suggestions would be greatly appreciated